# How can I define a mask function based on the values of a list in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to mask a tensor based on its values. In the following function if I pass a range (second part) it works, but I want to have a list with various values `prompt_ids` (3, 8, 9, 30). But it doesn't work and throws error.

```
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

The function:

```
   def get_prompt_token_fn(self):
        if self.prompt_ids:
            return lambda x: x in self.prompt_ids
        else:
            return lambda x: (x>=self.id_offset)&(x<self.id_offset+self.length)
```

What's the problem and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

In `pytorch 1.10` there is an `isin` function that returns a boolean array based on the condition that elements of first array are in the second array. For versions lower than it, you can implement it as follows:

```
def isin(ar1, ar2):
    return (ar1[..., None] == ar2).any(-1)
```